# How to implement SIP(Session Initiation Protocol) using TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, sip, voip

I learnt that SIP can be implemented using UDP.
Is there a way the same can be implemented using TCP ???

Thanks

Comment: According to RFC 3261, SIP can run either on TCP or UDP.

Answer (score 1):

SIP can not only work with UDP and TCP but also with other Transport layer protocols, like SCTP, or Application layer protocols like TLS. For a brief introduction I suggest reading [Wikipedia page about SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)

SIP also allows you to switch transport protocols during the session (for example, if a message overpasses Maximum Transfer Unit size).